# Add city name by default during checkout flow in Prestashop 1.7.6.1

Tags: prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I am creating a website for my store using Prestashop where we currently serve only in one city.

I was able to give only one option for the State and Country name but I am not able to do that for a city name.

I am using Prestashop version 1.7.6.1 and using the default theme.

can I do it using the admin panel or do I have to modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

In backoffice you must create your own "area" for delivery to limit your shipping mode to the city you want.

Comment: i will try and let you know.